# Path extractions swift 3.0

Tags: swift, string

I have a file path ...

`/acme101/acmeX100/acmeX100.008.png`

I can use this to get the extension `.png in this case`

```
let leftSide =  (lhs.fnName as NSString).pathExtension
```

And this to get the filename `acmeX100`

```
let leftSide =  (lhs.fnName as NSString).lastPathComponent
```

But I want the bit in the middle... the 008 in this case?

Is there a nice one liner?

Comment: From `leftSide`, get the range of "." and get the part after it?

Comment: your one liner is a call to a custom function if you need to...

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the filepath takes that general form then this is (almost) a one-liner (I like to play it safe):

```
var filePath = "/acme101/acmeX100/acmeX100.008.png"

func extractComponentBetweenDots(inputString: String) -> String? {

    guard inputString.components(separatedBy: ".").count > 2  else { print("Incorrect format") ; return nil } // Otherwise not in the correct format, you caa add other tests

    return inputString.components(separatedBy: ".")[inputString.components(separatedBy: ".").count - 2]
```

}

Use as follows:

```
if let extractedString : String = extractComponentBetweenDots(inputString: filePath) {
    print(extractedString)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to make an example using the same technique as in your question - despite the fact that the downcasting to NSString makes the whole thing rather ugly, it works efficiently. This is in Swift 3 but it would be easy to port it back to Swift 2 if needed.

```
func getComponents(from str: String) -> (name: String, middle: String, ext: String) {
    let compo = (str as NSString).lastPathComponent as NSString
    let ext = compo.pathExtension
    let temp = compo.deletingPathExtension as NSString
    let middle = temp.pathExtension
    let file = temp.deletingPathExtension
    return (name: file, middle: middle, ext: ext)
}

let result = getComponents(from: "/acme101/acmeX100/acmeX100.008.png")

print(result.name) // "acmeX100"
print(result.middle) // "008"
print(result.ext) // "png"
```

If you only need the middle part:

```
func pluck(str: String) -> String {
    return (((str as NSString).lastPathComponent as NSString).deletingPathExtension as NSString).pathExtension
}

pluck(str: "/acme101/acmeX100/acmeX100.008.png") // "008"
```

Answer (score 0):

Bon,

Sparky thanks for your answer. I ended up with this .. which is the same and yet different.

```
func pluck(str:String) -> String {
    if !str.isEmpty {
        let bitZero = str.characters.split{$0 == "."}.map(String.init)
        if (bitZero.count > 2) {
            let bitFocus = bitZero[1]
            print("bitFocus \(bitFocus)")
            return(bitFocus)
        }
    }
    return("")
}
```